# Send embedded Word Doc in excel sheet as email body

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, ms-word

My current vba code sends an email with the content of this code in the body of the email and I want to change it so it sends the embedded word document I have in a hidden sheet called (Email) that has some images and text as well as text that gets filled in from the user-form filled out in this macro.

Here is the part of the code I'm currently using for the email

```
strMsg = "<p>Hello Good Day</p></br>" & _        "<p>¡Welcome!</p></br>" & _
        "<p><strong>Attached you will find:</strong></p></br>" & _
        "<ul><li>A welcome presentation.</li>" & _
        "<li>Your welcome letter</li>" & _
        "<li>Directions to you work location <SITE></li>" & _
        "<li>First day Guide and Agenda. (Please bring all of this with you)</li>"


strMsg = strMsg & "<li>Bring Copies of your documents.</li></ul>"


strMsg = strMsg & "<p>Your hire date is <strong><u><HIREDATE></u></strong>. Please be on time " & _
        "at the work location <SITE> (<ADDRESS>) at <strong><HIRETIME>, in <ROOM>.</strong></p></br>" & _
        "<p>Be reminded if you are late your hires date maybe pushed back</p></br>" & _
        "<p><strong>Notes</strong>:</p>" & _
        "<ul><li>Dont forget your picture ID</li>" & _
        "<li>If You have any questions please dial Ext <u>5280</u>." & _
        " 24 hours a day 7 days a week</li></ul></br>" & _
        "<p>Please let me know if you have any questions.</p></br>" & _
        "<p>Regards.</p>" & _
        "<p>" & Application.UserName & "</p>" & _
        "<p><a title='MYICON' target='_blank' rel='noopener'><img src='https://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/MYICON_logo_detail.png' width='157' height='85' /></a></p>"


strMsg = Replace(strMsg, "<SITE>", strSite)
strMsg = Replace(strMsg, "<HIREDATE>", strHireDate)
strMsg = Replace(strMsg, "<ADDRESS>", strSiteAddress)
strMsg = Replace(strMsg, "<HIRETIME>", strTime)
strMsg = Replace(strMsg, "<ROOM>", strSiteRoom)


   Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If olApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Outlook is not available!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
```

Here is the code I tired to program calling the sheet but doesn't work

```
With WB


    .Worksheets("Email").Visible = True
    .Worksheets("Email").Copy Before:=WB.Worksheets(WB.Worksheets.Count)
    .Worksheets("Email").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    .Worksheets("Email (2)").Shapes("objWordEmail").OLEFormat.Verb 2

On Error Resume Next
    Set WordDoc = GetObject(, "Word.Application").ActiveDocument


If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WordApp.Visible = False
        Set WordDoc = GetObject(, "Word.Application").ActiveDocument
End If

    With WordDoc
        With .Content.Find
        .Text = "<HIREDATE>"
        .Replacement.Text = strHireDate
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        .Text = "<HIRETIME>"
        .Replacement.Text = strTime
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        .Text = "<ROOM>"
        .Replacement.Text = strSiteRoom
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        .Text = "<CONTACTEXT>"
        .Replacement.Text = strContactPhoneExt
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End With
End With
```

I'm not sure as to what more I need to be able to only display the embedded word doc it just keeps displaying the same email as before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the views... I don't know if this is the right thing to do but I found another way to get this done by saving the email as a template and then calling upon it and filling it with the following code... I just hope this works out ok for the people that will be using my macro... if you have any other suggestions let me know but for now this is solved

```
    On Error GoTo 0
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If olApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Outlook is not available!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

Set olAppMsg1 = olApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\mypath\Onboarding Files\Confirmacion de ingreso.oft")
    With olAppMsg1
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "[ROOM]", strSiteRoom)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "[HIREDATE]", strHireDate)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "[HIRETIME]", strTime)
        .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "[CONTACTEXT]", strContactPhoneExt)
        .To = strEmpEmail
        .Importance = olImportanceHigh
        .Attachments.Add ("\\mypath\Onboarding Files\Aceptación de formatos en WD.PPTX")
        .Attachments.Add (pathSaveIDPass)
        .Attachments.Add (strZip)
        .Display

    End With
```